# How to set a random speed in a canvas

Tags: performance, animation, canvas, random

I'm trying to make the balls falling at a random speed but the speed is changing only when I reload the page/script, I would like to get a random speed dynamically, one ball comes at 5, the next one 1.4, next 2.6 and so on...

https://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/gKNoEE

I tried to use the following :

```
// set how fast the objects will fall
var spawnRateOfDescent = Math.random() * (5 - 0.5) + 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each ball should have its own unique speed property. You can add it as follows:

**First adjustment** (lines 72-73):

```
    image: images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)], // add a comma here
    speed: Math.random() * 10 + 3 // add this line and tweak the numbers to taste
```

**Second adjustment** in your `animate` function (line 107 [or 108 if you added a line]):

```
    object.y += object.speed; // instead of: object.y += spawnRateOfDescent;
```

Comment: You are a superstar! Thank you :-)

Comment: I also have an other question, I'm wondering why the pictures are a bit pixellated, do you have an idea?

Comment: I just tried to add : ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; in the onload function but not sure that helps

Comment: I don't think any of that stuff will help if you're trying to enlarge an image that isn't SVG. Your file format is `svg.png` which sounds more like PNG than SVG. SVG is scalable (enlargeable), but PNG can only be scaled down.